# Connect FreeTakServer with Sitaware Frontline

Tags: ssl

I am trying to exchange data between my FreeTakServer and Sitaware Frontline. Therefore I added a Outgoing Federation from the FTS to Frontline. But I am just getting an SSL error. What does it mean and how can I fix it ?

```
_ssl.c:1114: The handshake operation timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine if the issue is unique to your present setup, try connecting to the server from a different network or device.Verify that your device trusts the certificate that the server is using,see if there are any technical difficulties or downtime with the server you are attempting to connect to.